# Non-degeneracy of alternate form in definition of Symplectic groups

Tags: group-theory

(I am a very beginner in study of simple groups of Lie type.)

Let $\langle \,\,,\,\,\rangle\colon V\times V\rightarrow F$ be a *non-degenerate* bilinear form on $V$ such that for all $v,w\in V$,
$$\langle v,w\rangle =-\langle w,v\rangle.$$
Then the transformations $T\colon V\rightarrow V$ satisfting 
$$\langle T(v),T(w)\rangle =\langle v,w\rangle$$
are invertible (by non-degeneracy) and then they form a group, called a symplectic group over $F$.

My question is on the necessity of *non-degeneracy*; what problems are created if we drop it.

Suppose that there is another form $\langle \,\,,\,\,\rangle_1$ on $V$ (may or may not be degenerate) satisfying 
$$\langle v,w\rangle_1 =-\langle w,v\rangle_1,$$
and suppose we collect those *invertible transformations* $T\colon V\rightarrow V$ satisfying 
$$\langle T(v),T(w)\rangle_1 =\langle v,w\rangle_1.$$
Such transformations will necessarily form a subgroup $G$ of $GL(V)$. Are such groups studied? How long they differ from symplectic groups? Do they give simple groups of Lie type through their composition series?

Comment: They can be studied, but the associated symplectic groups do not act irreducibly on $V$ because they fix $V^\perp$. They are not in general simple. I think they tend to be parabolic subgroups of the symplectic group acting on a nondegenerate form.